# Core Data Unit Tests with in-memory store crash

Tags: macos, cocoa, unit-testing, swift, core-data

I am attempting to test my application's interaction with CoreData using an in-memory store, but the code crashes when I attempt to cast the object given from this call:

```
let newEntity: AnyObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("File", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
let newFile = newEntity as RSFile
```

`RSFile` is set properly in the Class field of the core data model and included in , and this code works fine in the normal application. I have checked that the Managed Object Model is being properly created, and everything seems to be setup properly, but I end up in the machine code with a `"dynamic cast failed"` string a few lines above the breakpoint.

Additionally, if I cast `newEntity` to an `NSManagedObject` and place a breakpoint so that I can inspect it at runtime, everything appears valid there, so the issue is solely with the cast. I've looked at other suggestions but I can't find anything missing from my configuration. Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

**Update**

I created an example project that demonstrates both a working core data interaction while the apps running, and the crash when you run the tests.
https://github.com/kujenga/CoreDataIssue

Comment: How are you running the tests? Is the simulator started when the tests are being run?

Comment: The application is for Mac, not iOS, but yes, the application is running.

Comment: It might be a namespace problem. Is the managed object subclass declared as `Package.RSFile` in the model? If so, try simplifying to `RSFile`.

Comment: No, I tried that solution after reading the post here: http://www.jessesquires.com/swift-coredata-and-testing/ but then my regular application code crashed as well, saying that the namespaced class could not be found. So I changed it back to just `RSFile`.

Comment: Maybe you have added the class to both targets. Instead, you should `import` your main app package in the test class.

Answer (score 2):

In a simple test project I made it work like this:

1. Make sure the classes are not added also to the test target.
2. Import your MyApp package on top of your test class.
3. Cast with `as?`.

Like this:

```
var newEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
   "File", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? PSFile
```

**EDIT**

After ascertaining that the above does indeed return `nil` (only in the test class), here is my working solution:

1. Make all the classes you need in the test `public`, including the managed object subclasses.
2. In case of the managed objects, you also need to make the attributes (properties) that you intend to access public.
3. Don't add the classes to the test target (if you do, the cast will fail).
4. Instead, add `import YourAppName` to the test file.
5. Use an unconditional cast.

Like this [tested]:

```
let newEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(
   "File", inManagedObjectContext: moc) as! RSFile
```

Comment: I currently have all the swift files from my main app target added to the compile sources of my test target, and removing the RSFile from there causes a multitude of compile errors wherever the RSFile type is used in my application. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong by adding these files to the target? Also, casting with `as?` just produces a nil value since the cast fails, and the program crashes when I try to unwrap it.

Comment: If you have a moment to compare the project that I linked to in the question update to your test project, let me know what the difference is. Otherwise, if you are able to post your code somewhere I would love to take a look.